# How Can I truncate overflowed text using ellipsis in description rows from Product List?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Is there a way

```
                              e.g
```

instead I have "product 1 is the best from the industry" I try this "product 1..."

This is my code:

```
           import React, { Component } from 'react';
           import { connect } from 'react-redux';
           import { searchProducts, deleteProduct } from '../../actions';
           import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
           const moment = require('moment');


            class ProductList extends Component {
                      componentDidMount() {
                      this.props.searchProducts();
                         }


                  runFiles() {
                      return this.props.productList.map(product => {
                          return (
                         <tr key={product._id}>
                     <td style={{fontStyle: 'italic',fontWeight:'500'}}>{product.name}</td>
              {/*IN THE FOLLOWING ONE LINE I WANT TO TRUNCATE DESCRIPTION*/}
                    <td style={{fontStyle: 'italic',fontWeight:'500'}}>{product.description}</td>
                          <td style={{fontStyle: 'italic',fontWeight:'500'}}>{product.brand}</td>
                            <td style={{fontStyle: 'italic',fontWeight:'500'}}>{product.price}</td>
                   <td style={{fontStyle: 'italic',fontWeight:'500'}}>{product.stock}</td>
                         <td style={{fontStyle: 'italic',fontWeight:'500'}}>{product.code}</td>
                      <td style={{fontStyle: 'italic',fontWeight:'500'}}>{producto.isPassedAway}</td>
                          <td style={{fontStyle: 'italic',fontWeight:'500'}}> 
                       {moment(product.createdAt).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss')}</td>
                               <td style={{fontStyle: 'italic',fontWeight:'500'}}> 
                             {moment(product.passedAwayAt).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss')}</td>
                                  <td>
                                <Link to={`/products/${product._id}/show`} className='mr-2' style= 
                           {{fontWeight:'bold',color:'blue'}}>
                                   show
                                   </Link>
                             <Link to={`/products/${product._id}/edit`} className='mr-2' style= 
                                {{fontWeight:'bold',color:'blue'}}>
                                   Edit
                                       </Link>
                                      <a
                                     className='mr-2'
                                       style={{fontWeight:'bold',color:'blue'}}
                                        href='#more'
                                        onClick={() => {
                                      if (
                                          window.confirm(
                                 '¿Are you sure to want to delete the product?' + ' ' + product.name
                                            )
                                          )


                                      this.props.deleteProduct(product._id);

                                          }}
                                            >
                                      Delete
                                      </a>
                                      </td>
                                      </tr>
                                          );
                                     });
                                           }

                                          render() {
                                                 return (
                                                  <div>
                                          <h2><b>Listing products</b></h2>

                                         <p>
                                 <Link to='/products/new' className= 'btn btn-primary' style= 
                          {{fontWeight:'bold',color:'black'}}>
                                 New
                                  </Link>
                                     </p>

                                 <div className='table-responsive'>
                                   <table className='table table-sm'>
                                <thead className='thead-light'>
                                        <tr>
                                       <th style={{fontStyle: 'arial'}}>Name</th>
                                       <th style={{fontStyle: 'arial'}}>Description</th>
                                       <th style={{fontStyle: 'arial'}}>Brand</th>
                                       <th style={{fontStyle: 'arial'}}>Price</th>
                                       <th style={{fontStyle: 'arial'}}>Stock</th>
                                       <th style={{fontStyle: 'arial'}}>Code</th>
                                       <th style={{fontStyle: 'arial'}}>Is passed Away</th>
                                       <th style={{fontStyle: 'arial'}}>Created At</th>
                                       <th style={{fontStyle: 'arial'}}>Passed Away At</th>
                                       <th style={{fontStyle: 'arial'}}>Actions</th>
                                          </tr>
                                          </thead>
                                       <tbody>{this.runFiles()}</tbody>
                                       </table>
                                       </div>
                                       </div>
                                    );
                                        }
                                         }

                        function mapState(state) {
                                   return {
                                  productList: state.productsDs.productList
                                       };
                                           }

                              const actions = {
                                      searchProducts,
                                      deleteProduct
                                          };


                                  export default connect(
                                         mapState,
                                           actions
                                        )(ProductList);
```

My productList fetched to componentDidMount is following:

```
                 [product1:{name: "product 1",description:"the product 1 is biggest of the 
                      factory"},...//OTHER FIELDS]
```

I want something like this:

```
                        product 1: {name: "product1", description: "the product 1..."//OTHER FIELDS,... }

                   in every description rows form each product I want to truncate text with ellipsis.
```

I know it's possible truncate the text on determinate part from the parragraph. Say prod1... instead prod1 is the best of the industry.

anyone who can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that by adding some css to the description cell.

```css
.truncate {
  width: [width];
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

`<td className="truncate" style={{fontStyle: 'italic',fontWeight:'500'}}>{product.description}</td>`